# High fill rate, low impressions - a bug in adMob?

Tags: android, admob, ads, facebook-sdk-4.0, rewardedvideoad

I have finally put some rewarded video ads in my trivia game.
Currently, I have around 1,000 active users a week with very low impressions.
I noticed my problem while testing my app again: it will deliver an ad very rarely to the users, I mean, once the user had seen an ad, it would take A LOT of time until he could see another one (when in most cases it will not show ad at all),
Even if he would close and open the app again.

VERY IMPORTANT:
1. I have a very high fill rate (96%) which might suggest that the problem is that the adMob SDK is not sending the requests all the time.
2. I have tested my adMod ad unit in the adMob rewarded video example app and it worked fine! The app showed me videos one after another with no delay!
3. I have Facebook sdk integrated in my app in the same activity where the rewarded videos show for a 'Share' button.

All these facts made me think that it might be my code that is causing all of this, but in the other hand, if my code was bad - why would the app show me videos at all?
In addition, my adMob code is taken from their website - stayed untouched except the app id and ad unit id.

Thanks, hope the problem is clear.

Comment: do you have frequency capping setup on the ad unit?

Comment: @MStoner No, everything is normal and no limits are set.

Comment: Even if there's a frequency cap, the lower one should be the match rate not impression rate.

Answer (score 1):

High fill rate with low impression means that you request the ad and you receive it successfully, but the ad doesn't appear to the users.
it may be occur if the ads take long time to appear, so it appears after the user scrolls to another place or opens another screen.
it may also appear if the users countries have low internet connection strength.

Comment: When I tested the app I have waited for ever a lot of times and still. None were displayed.

Comment: Mine is displayed well, but still the impression rate are very low(38%) on iOS. The one on Android is 91%. Don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same issue. As we are using AdMob, we checked for one of our app on Oct 6, 2017 that match rate was 97% but show rate was 0.84% for interstitial ads in South Africa. It is better for banner ads but still it is less in comparison to other apps. Match rate is 95% for banner ads and show rate is 70% which is very low as our other apps are working fine in South Africa. I would suggest you to use other ad networks for mediation.